# HTML code inside templates isn't processing Django code

Tags: python, django

I'm a complete beginner in Django.I'm not able to extract data from my database inside the template. Please cooperate and help!

mysite/books/templates/books/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
{% for book in object_list %}
  <h>{‌{book.name }}</h>
{% endfor %}
</html>
```

mysite/books/views.py

```
# Create your views here.
from django.views import generic
from .models import Book
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'books/index.html'


    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.all()

class BookCreate(CreateView):
    model = Book
    fields = ['name', 'author', 'price', 'type', 'book_image']


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Book
    template_name = 'books/detail.html'
```

mysite/books/models.py

```
# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Book(models.Model):

    def get_absoulte_url(self):
        return reverse('books:detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + '-' + self.author

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    book_image = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

output

[Please click to see the output screenshot.{{book.name}} is not getting processed in the template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcOwU.png)

Comment: `<h> </h>` isn't a template tag.  And you do not have `<body>` tags. Could it be that?

Comment: try putting it in an `<ul>` and have `<li>{{book.name}}</li>`

Comment: Tried both the things but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have a hidden character in your html template:

```
{<200c>{book.name }}
```

Delete your opening curly braces and re-type them. It should work fine after that.